# Fill table with data relying on 5 other tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to fill up a relation table in MySQL only using (My)SQL-statements. The problem, why I am stucking right now is, that I have to fill the data relying on other tables with conditions. I never did much with conditional programming and looping inside sql and every part I tried right now to make it somehow work failed miserably. I maybe want to store the result as a stored procedure later but for now a working statement would be more than satisfying.

Table Setup:

I have 5 tables with data and I need to fill a sixth one with relationship data. the table structure looks like this:

[image: table setup]

Now I want to fill in the data for CategoryProducts only using sql (MySQL) with the following rules (pseudo code)

```
foreach category-id:
  if allTags is true then
    fetch each product-id that has all tags that the category has
  else
    fetch each product-id that has at least one tag that the category has
  fi

  insert each product-id matching into CategoryProducts
end foreach
```

To be honest, I have NO idea how to accomplish this, only using plain sql. I usually would achieve this by code but this time I cannot do this. I want to use this as a part of a setup script for one of our foreign servers, but during this part of the setup routine I can only execute SQL statements.

Edit: removed the ugly mouse cursor in the table setup picture.

Comment: This question leaves me a bit confused.  It might help if you posted the table definitions instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this with a 'simple' INSERT..SELECT:

```
insert into CategoryProducts(cID, pID)
select
  -- The field list in `select` should match the list in the `insert into` clause.
  x.cID,
  x.pID
from
  -- Inner select returns all possible combinations, yet unfiltered by the
  -- conditions you specified, and returns the number of tags 
  -- for each product, each catagory, and the number of tags they share. 
  -- If SharedTagCount = cTagCount, it means that the product has all the tags 
  -- of the category (not necessarily the other way around).
  (select
    p.ID as pID,
    c.ID as cID,
    c.allTags,
    (select count(*) from ProductTags pt where pt.pID = p.ID) as pTagCount,
    (select count(*) from CategoryTags ct where ct.cID = c.ID) as cTagCount,
    (select
      count(*)
    from
      ProductTags pt
      inner join CategoryTags ct on ct.tCode = pt.tCode
    where
      pt.pID = p.ID and
      ct.cID = c.ID) as SharedTagCount
  from
    Product p
    cross join Categories c) x
where
  -- Outer select filters. 
  -- if SharedTagCount = cTagCount, it means that the product has all 
  -- the tags of the category.
  ( x.AllTags and
    x.cTagCount = x.SharedTagCount) or
  -- if SharedTagCount > 0, it means the product has at least one tag of the category.
  ( (not x.AllTags) and
    x.SharedTagCount > 0)
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I can stack the select at this way in an insert statement. I will check this out now.

Comment: So, i tried it on the development. It seems to work, but after the first 10.000 entries it lost connection to the database. I need to figure it out where this comes from. I thank you for your answer for now, but I need to verify the result first. :)

Comment: Ok it does way to long to execute. I am still figuring out how to reduce the execution time. After 15 minutes it was still not done. I went through the keys / indices but there is nothing i can alter there on table basis, maybe i can alter the joins in the statements to get the same effect. i will write back -

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Maybe you can optimize the inner query a bit by filtering out products and categories that have no tags at all, and those that don't share tags. Also, you may temporarily create a table with the result from the inner query, or just from the cross join and work from there. If you have many products and/or categories, this query will have to deal with a huge amount of data. And because you are using all the data, indexes will probably hardly be used. Nevertheless, my query is a bit crude (basic functionality only), but it can be optmized or broken up if you really need to.

Comment: yes, the problem is the cross join. I am dealing with about 16k products and 1k categories. this is a cross join set of 16million rows. thats a big too much I guess :)

Comment: 16 million isn't that bad, although it might be if the server is a bit short on memory. Still, saving intermediate results in temporary tables might make it a lot easier for the database. By the way, is this a one time process, or do you need to repeat it on a regular base?

Comment: I want to have something lika a init data file. The idea behind this that if I demand i press a button on my base server and get an large SQL file (maybe 300mb) and transfer it to another srv with all products, categories and tags and a recreation of all relations. The data of the products, cats and tags is no problem but the recreation of the relations is a bit of a problem. There are a few shops and every shop has a subset of products and a subset of categories. the products getting categorized by the tag combination, but I need a relation table for performance issues (and other stuff)

Comment: and no, the relation table has to get build on the server what reads in the sql file, not the server who creates the sql file (before the questions comes up) :)